# MongoDB count from given id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I have a question regarding querying from MongoDB.

I have a chat module, that I have created in MongoDB.

When the messages are queried from the frontend it queried so that the newest message is retrieved first

Currently, my query looks like this

```
  async findChatHistory(query: ChatHistroyDto): Promise<Chat[]> {
    return await this.chatModel
      .find({
        $or: [
          { fromUserId: query.fromUserId, toUser: query.toUserId },
          { fromUserId: query.toUserId, toUser: query.fromUserId },
        ],
      }, null, {limit: query.limit})
      .sort({ timeStamp: 'asc' })
  }
```

This works fine, but I would like to add a second parameter to add as an offset/skip.

The problem is, that multiple messages can be persisted before the users access this service method again, so ideally it would be something like `{lastMessageId: '123', limit: 10}`.
Because of the order we retrieve the messages in, we need to count backwards from the `lastMessageId`.
So the client can provide the id of the last message received, and MongoDB will start to query from that id.

example
client requests lastMessageId: null, limit: 3

```
msg1, msg2, msg3
```

client requests: lastmessageId: 'msg3', limit: 2

```
msg4, msg5
```

Comment: So? Just add that clause, `_id: {$gt: query.lastMessageId}`. Note, if you're using a field as a cursor like this, you need to sort by this field too.

Comment: Should it not be `$lt` ? Because it should go in ascending order?

Comment: I don't see how `$lt` would help with ascending order.

Comment: We agree on the fact that the `_id` is incrementing right?
So if I want the retrieve all the messages before some `_id` we would have to use a `$lt` right?.

if we have id's 1-20 (1 being the oldest) the query would be something like.

now i would like to get all messages with `lastMessageId: 10` limit: 5

in that case i would need to get message with `_ìd` `5-10` ?

Comment: if 10 is the last message you already received, why would you want to receive 6-10 again? Do you not want to receive 11-15 now?

Comment: But we receive the newest messages first right, so it would start off by getting `20-10` (if we have limit 10. Then when we need to get more messages, we provide `lastMessageId: 10 ``and query down `until we reach message_id 1`, the first message received. ?

Comment: This looks more like a descending order, though. But yes, in this case you'd use `$lt`

Comment: "But we receive the newest messages first right" - not what I assumed from reading your question. You should spell out details like this.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I have updated the question description